# Check for empty textfield

Tags: java, javafx, input, textfield

Okay, so, what I have, is supposed to be a simple dice roller. 2 textfields, one for the number of die you want to roll, and the other for the total. (Well, and a third for each individual die rolled, but that's besides the point) This works fine, as long as the number of die text field isn't empty. When the field is empty, I just get a `NumberFormatException`

My code:

```
        Button d4 = new Button("d4  ");
    d4.setLayoutX(240);
    d4.setLayoutY(90);
    d4.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            tooltip.setText("");                
            int d4_num = Integer.parseInt(d4_text.getText()); //d4_text is for the number of die
            d4_num = d4_num + 1;
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < d4_num; i++){
                int result = 1 + (int)(Math.random() *4);
                sum = sum += result;
                tooltip.appendText((String.valueOf("d4_" + i + " =" + result + "\n")));

            }
            d4_result.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }
    });
```

I've tried checking the value of `d4_text` in different ways, each one either giving an error because I can't check for null, or a string, or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To safely check for 'whether the field contains an integer value' you could do the following:

```
final String fieldValue = d4_text.getText();
if (fieldValue != null && fieldValue.matches("\\d+")) {
    int d4_num = Integer.parseInt(fieldValue);
    ... the rest of your logic that relies on having a correct d4_num value
} else {
    ... output some error message like 'please enter a few digits'
}
```

Here you check that the field contains a non-null string which consists only of digits, at least one.

There is still a possibility that a user would break this entering a number that is too long for `int`; you could also add some reasonable restriction on field value length:

```
if (fieldValue != null && fieldValue.matches("\\d{2}")) {
```

Here, only numbers consisting exactly of 2 digits will be accepted.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! Basically exactly what I was trying to do, but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch that exception, and set it to zero in case of `NumberFormatException`

```
int d4_num;

try {
    d4_num = Integer.parseInt(d4_text.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    d4_num = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this before pass the integer value

```
if (d4_text.getText() == null || d4_text.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
 // your code here }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried checking the value of d4_text in different ways, each one
>   either giving an error because I can't check for null, or a string, or
>   whatever.

First :  check that the field is not `null` (Note that by default Java FX input textfields are not null but a tricky client code may change it) and not empty(by trimming the whitespaces). 
Second : check that it is a number or catch the exception.

Using an `Integer` rather than `int` helps to determinate if the submitted value is a `Integer`.  `Integer` that accepts the `null` value may convey a failing input but `int` that is necessary valued with a numeric value cannot.

```
Integer d4_num = null;
String textToConvertToInt = d4_text.getText();
if (textToConvertToInt != null && !textToConvertToInt.trim().equals("")){
   try{
       d4_num = Integer.parseInt(textToConvertToInt); 
   }
   catch (NumberFormatException e){
     // handle the exception
   }
 }
```

You can also use [apache-common-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api.2.0/) to do it :

```
String textToConvertToInt = d4_text.getText();
Integer d4_num = null;
if (NumberUtils.isNumber(textToConvertToInt)){
  d4_num = Integer.parseInt(textToConvertToInt );
}
```